# How do I make sure that a Java thread will never run an infinite loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm doing a project that reads a computer's energy consumption. For some background, the energy reading is done at the low level in C, but I'm working on a Java application that uses native calls to get the readings and then do some higher level stuff with them.

What I'm working on right now is making an `EnergyReadingCollector` object that runs as a thread, grabbing and storing readings until you tell it to stop. You can use this while some other code is running and then you have a bunch of data at the end of this about how the program consumed energy. Makes for some pretty looking graphs to impress the ladies, yknow ;)

My issue arises when the section of code that you're tracking is super quick. No issues arise with long stretches, but sometimes my program runs an infinite loop on quick bits.

Here is my class. I left out a lot of details because this question just pertains to the threading aspect of this program. I think this is enough to show what's going on.

```
public class EnergyReadingCollector implements Runnable
{
    private ArrayList<double> readings;
    private volatile boolean exit = false;

    public void run()
    {
        readings.clear();
        exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            double reading = getReading();
            readings.add(reading);
        }
    }

    public void end()
    {
        exit = true;
    }

}
```

Simple use case:

```
EnergyReadingCollector ec = new EnergyReadingCollector();
new Thread(ec).start();
//code section to track
ec.end();
```

The `ec` object now has an internally stored list of all of the energy readings that happened during this code section.

I think an infinite loop happens because the quick code is over before the thread even starts. So it executes and `ec.end()` happens, but *then* the thread starts up and waits for `ec.end()` to happen. It didn't realize that the ship had already sailed and is stuck waiting forever.

Am I right about why this is happening? And if so, how can I prevent this? Is the only solution to guarantee that the code being tracked runs for at least a certain amount of time? This might sound reasonable at first, since it doesn't make sense to track energy consumption for a few microseconds of code. However, the code could have an exception that causes it to abort prematurely, so I'd rather there be some way to handle this situation. There's also the option of removing the `exit = false;` line from the beginning of my `run()` method, but I put that in there to make sure the same object can be used to collect energy multiple different times in one program.

Is there a thread safety convention for this type of situation?

Also, what do you think of the name `EnergyReadingCollector`? It's not my favorite, but it seems descriptive enough and I can't think of anything better. Open to suggestions with it :)

EDIT:
I did what one one the comments said about setting `exit` to false in its own `reinit()` method. It actually makes more sense and I have other functionality that I can put into it to. Haven't had any problems since, so that was probably the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Don't initialize exit within the run method.  if you want to be able to reuse the instance then create a reset method that resets the exit variable to false.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi is right about not initializing `exit` in `run`. For details, please see my answer. If one of the answers is helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The begin phase creates the `Runnable` and starts the thread, which is an asynchronous operation:

```
EnergyReadingCollector ec = new EnergyReadingCollector();
                        // Thread A: ec.exit = false;
new Thread(ec).start(); // Thread B: ec.exit = false;
                        // Thread B: while (!ec.exit) {
```

The end phase sets the flag:

```
ec.end();               // Thread A: ec.exit = true;
```

Assuming a near-zero execution time of the code in the energy consumption "section", the following order of events is possible (lost update), which leads to an infinite loop:

```
// EnergyReadingCollector ec = new EnergyReadingCollector();
Thread A: ec.exit = false;
// new Thread(ec).start();
Thread A: ec.exit = true;
Thread B: ec.exit = false;
Thread B: while (!ec.exit) {
```

To address this, all you need to do is remove the initialization in `run()`, it's not necessary as there's an initializer for `exit`.

Please note that you should always wait for thread completion via `Thread.join()`. Otherwise, a new thread might be started in a subsequent energy consumption section even though the last thread is still running, which might lead to hitting resource limits.

Getting back to the initialization of `exit`. If the `Runnable` instance is supposed to be reusable, you could reset `exit` before leaving `run()`. In any case, you have to make sure that the thread is not running anymore before reusing the instance. `Thread.join()` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I think an infinite loop happens because the quick code is over before the thread even starts. So it executes and ec.end() happens, but then the thread starts up and waits for ec.end() to happen. It didn't realize that the ship had already sailed and is stuck waiting forever.

I don't this this is the case. Lets assume this was true. I that case,

```
        while (!exit) {
          double reading = getReading();
          readings.add(reading);
        }
```

the while loop would not have run at all since **exit** is true.

I can see 3 possible scenarios which might be causing the thread to not reach the exit condition:

- The `getReading()` call never completes. This can be checked by adding a breakpoint (or a print statement, if a debug environment is not setup)in the next line.
- The code between `start()` and `end()` never completes.
- The code between  `start()` and `end()` throws an exepction which is caught in a larger scope which is not included in the sample code above.

Can you test for these possibilities and post what you find?

Edit:

I think the name `EnergyReadingCollector` is fine. You could change it to `EnergyLevelCollector` if you don't like the former.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `exit` isn't volatile. So there is no happens before relation between setting the value to true and reading the value.

The JIT could decide to hoist the reading of the value out of the loop:

```
if(exit) return;
while(true){
   .. stuff
}
```

Comment: it says right in the code i posted ```exit``` is volatile